# Adding a new row in a matrix, every other row, whose elements are averages of the elements above and below it

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, average

I have a matrix, say:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
    [4, 5, 6]
    [7, 8, 9]
```

and I want to construct another matrix, having two extra rows as such

```
B = [1,    2,    3]
    [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
    [4,     5,   6]
    [5.5, 6.5, 7.5]
    [7,     8,   9]
```

where every element on the second and fourth row is the average of the elements above and below it.

I want to do this, in python, numpy, for an n x m matrix.

EDIT: The generalization to this would be to insert the means of two neighboring rows every n rows. For example

```
     A = [ 1,  2,  3]
         [ 4,  5,  6]
         [ 7,  8,  9]
         [10, 11, 12]
         [13, 14, 15]
         [16, 17, 18]
         [19, 20, 21]
```

and , for n = 3 , B would become

```
     B = [ 1,  2,  3]
         [ 4,  5,  6]
         [ 7,  8,  9]
         [8.5, 9.5, 10.5]
         [10, 11, 12]
         [13, 14, 15]
         [16, 17, 18]
         [17.5, 18.5, 19.5]
         [19, 20, 21]
```

and so on. The AVERAGE layers are still the average of the one above and the one below them. I am looking for a function that would give this for any n.

Comment: So, in the edited code, each `AVERAGE` would be a block of three rows, right?

Comment: Nop, so each average would be a single row, just as in the first example. Everything is identical, except for the fact that you include the average row every n rows , not every 2.

Comment: Could you add the exact expected output for the edited code?

Comment: Ok, I modified the example, the averages are the two rows with floating point numbers.

Comment: What if `A` is say a `(9 x 3)` shaped array and thus for `n = 3`, doesn't have anything for the below after the third `AVERAGE`? Should we still compute the third `AVERAGE` or skip or such a case won't happen?

Comment: Well then it should just do as many averages as fit into the size of A. If it does not have one of the rows with which to compute the average, it can leave the original row where it was (i.e. not compute) the last average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach making use of  slicing -

```
newvals = (A[1:] + A[:-1])/2.0
out = np.empty((A.shape[0]+newvals.shape[0],A.shape[1]))
out[::2] = A
out[1::2] = newvals
```

Here's another one with `np.insert` for a generic case -

```
np.insert(A.astype(float),range(1,A.shape[0]),newvals,axis=0)
```

---

Generalizing to handle every possible `n` -

```
def insert_row_averages(A, n=1):
    slice2 = A[n::n]
    v = (A[n-1::n][:slice2.shape[0]] + slice2)/2.0
    return np.insert(A.astype(float),n*np.arange(1,v.shape[0]+1),v,axis=0)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [195]: A0
Out[195]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [196]: insert_row_averages(A0, n=1)
Out[196]: 
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
       [ 4. ,  5. ,  6. ],
       [ 5.5,  6.5,  7.5],
       [ 7. ,  8. ,  9. ]])

In [197]: A
Out[197]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21]])

In [198]: insert_row_averages(A, n=3)
Out[198]: 
array([[  1. ,   2. ,   3. ],
       [  4. ,   5. ,   6. ],
       [  7. ,   8. ,   9. ],
       [  8.5,   9.5,  10.5],
       [ 10. ,  11. ,  12. ],
       [ 13. ,  14. ,  15. ],
       [ 16. ,  17. ,  18. ],
       [ 17.5,  18.5,  19.5],
       [ 19. ,  20. ,  21. ]])
```

Comment: any idea on how the last one can be modified to do the same ,but not every second row, say every n-th row?

Comment: @Qubix I am not sure on where you would like to place the computed means. Add a sample case into the question for say `n = 3` with a bigger `A`?

Comment: it works perfectly even for very large matrices. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to calculate the averages and then insert it back to `A`:

```
np.insert(A.astype(float), [1,2], (A[1:] + A[:-1])/2, axis=0)

#array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
#       [ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
#       [ 4. ,  5. ,  6. ],
#       [ 5.5,  6.5,  7.5],
#       [ 7. ,  8. ,  9. ]])
```